# Not able to receive firebase push notification

Tags: java, ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using JAVA admin SDK for sending the push notification. I have two clients (Android & iOS). Trying to send the push notification to FCM ids. Able to receive notification in android client side. But not receiving an iOS client.

When I am sending notification through firebase console able to receive push notification in both clients.

Here is code for receiving push notification in iOS client

```
  if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    Messaging.messaging().isAutoInitEnabled = true

              // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
       func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: 
          @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    print(userInfo)
    completionHandler()
}
```